# Docker образ в kubernetes. Прошу экспертного мнения

Tags: linux, docker, kubernetes

Здравствуйте Я недавно начал изучать kubernetes. В связи с чем хотел бы проконсультироваться.

1. Недавно задался вопросом как можно образы docker интегрировать в kubernetes. На сколько Я понимаю это docker registry через который нужно pull-ить и push-ить.
2. Есть ли более оптимальный вариант решения вопроса, в Kubernetes-е создание и сборки образов docker ? (сори что много пишу, просто не знаю как спросить)

   Задаюсь вопросом можно ли сделать так (к примеру):

   1. Условна создать контейнер настроить так как мне нужно

      ```
      docker run -it tomcat /bin/sh
      docker commit -m "test" tomcat
      ```
   2. и уже созданный имейдж загрузить в кубернетейс
      предварительно грохнув контейнер docker-а.

      ```
      docker rm tomcat.
      ```

   ????
3. Может есть оптимальный какой либо путь ? 
   Есть ли какая нибудь вменяемая статья на эту тему ?

Comment: Я в Кубернетес не умею, но тут чувак начал писать с самого начала. Может что подчерпнёшь: https://serveradmin.ru/tag/kubernetes/

Comment: а какой kubetnetes вы используете Minikube или встроенный в docker for desktop или вообще облака?

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению нет.
Как вариант после загрузки в docker-registry можно использовать docker-compose и делать установку через image

Comment: вы хотите запускать контейнеры из созданного имиджа в кубернейтс?